# Is there a standard name for this function?

Tags: functional-programming, terminology, naming, higher-order-functions

What would you name a function that takes a list and a function, and returns True if applying the function to all elements gives the same result?

```
def identical_results(l, func):
    if len(l) <= 1: return True
    result = func(l[0])
    for el in l[1:]:
        if func(el) != result:
            return False
    return True
```

Is there a nice generally accepted name for this thing? Bonus if you can implement in a less clunky fashion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .NET, the closest is `Array.TrueForAll`.

Maybe `SameForAll` would be more appropriate for this function?

Comment: Oh, thx: SameForAll is indeed the best proposition I heard yet

Answer (score 4):

Havn't heard about a special name for this yet (somewhat similar to `Forall`, but not exactly). `IdenticalResults` seems okay so (Jon Seigel proposed `SameForAll`, also quite nice)

Additionally: That's the way one could implement this in Haskell using the `all` function (`TrueForall` under .NET)

```
ident [] = True
ident (x:xs) = all (== x) xs

sameForAll f = ident . map f
```

And Python:

```
def idents(f, list):
    if len(list) <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        let fx0 = f(list[0])
        return all(( f(x) == fx0 for x in list[1:] ))
```

Comment: it's pretty much testing if the function is constant over a domain.

Comment: Not sure about the Haskell one, but the python one seems to return True if all items are identical. That's cool, because now I can call `idents(map(f, list))` to implement SameForAll. Fix up your code so I can give you an upvote...

Comment: Oops, I just forgot to apply f ;-)

Comment: Oh, I think I'm getting the Haskell one, and you should either do `\el -> f el == f x` or `\el -> el = x` and then `sameforall = idents map` (right?)

Comment: @Dario but if you do it with `map` you only call f once on the first element.

Comment: Haskell will cache this anyway. Nevertheless now it's even cooler ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Can't think of a good name so far, but this one does the same:

```
def identical_results(l, func):
    return len(set(map(func, l))) <= 1
```

Comment: Very concise code, but inefficient since creating a set requires O(n log n) whereas the algorithm should just need O(n).

Comment: @Dario: True, if that's an issue.

Comment: Yep, right idea balpha.  reduce() will merge the results without creating a set:

def identical_results(l, func):
    return reduce(lamdba x,y: x and y, map(func, l))

Since it's map+reduce, this is highly scaleable too (see Google's Mapreduce paper).

Comment: @Lee B: What you're proposing does not have the same functionality.

Comment: In Python, sets are implemented as hash tables, not as binary trees, so set creation is O(n), not O(n log n).

Comment: @Roberto Bonvallet: I didn't know that. Is that consistent among implementations? Anyhow, I'd worry about performance of such a function only when you know (read: can prove) that it's an issue. When creating a function like `identical_results()`, assuming it's being called on relatively small lists and not too often, any time spent on thinking about performance is wasted. Especially in a case (like here) where you have very well-defined inputs and outputs, making it easier to later implement an optimized version, should the need arise.

Answer (score 0):

identical_results sounds like a reasonable name to me.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this in a comment above, but the formatting got messed up, so here it is again for clarity:

```
def identical_results(l, func):
    return reduce(lamdba x,y: x and y, map(func, l))
```

Comment: I think you have the right idea, but as it is now, you've implemented TrueForAll instead of SameAll

Comment: right.  I was thinking the function could do all the work (and it can), but it probably would be nicer if reduce checked an array and only added new values.  That pretty much would be a set anyway though, like balpha suggested above.